# javascript how to filter an object array based on another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Here is the example, Please help with equivalent javascript code

```
array A = [{id: 1, name:'cat'},{id:2, name:'dog'},{id:3, name:'tiger'}];

array B = [{name:'cat'},{name:'dog'}];
```

result

```
expected = [{id: 1, name:'cat'},{id:2, name:'dog'}];
```

Need to filter Array A based on names available in array B

Similar to SQL where name in `('cat','dog')`.

Tried to use `array.filter` and `indexOf !== -1`

But not getting the expected result.

Comment: Show what you tried,those are things that should work if you used then right.

Comment: Adding the code as requested by Paul - arrayFilter(A,B) {
const Result= A.filter((o) =>
B.indexOf(o.name) !== -1);
return Result;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the arrays grow bigger, it's probably better to build a lookup object, but a simple approach using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) could look as follows:

```js
const a = [{id: 1, name:'cat'}, {id:2, name:'dog'}, {id:3, name:'tiger'}];
const b = [{name:'cat'}, {name:'dog'}];

const result = a.filter(x => b.some(y => x.name === y.name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   const a = [{id: 1, name:'cat'}, {id:2, name:'dog'}, {id:3,    name:'tiger'}];
 const b = [{name:'cat'}, {name:'dog'}];


                    

           
   var res = a.filter((per)=>b.find((x)=>per.name===x.name))
   
   console.log(res)
```